# Missing localisation modules? version 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, messages, ce-1.9.2.1, password-recovery

I’m working in a store with 2 views – EN and PT.

When I try the recover password, I receive a message in English on the screen in both views (If there is an account associated with abc@abc.pt you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.)

Where and how can I find this message to translate it?

Comment: I do some searching on magento files and the string is translated in the file 'locale\pt_PT'.
There's 2 places where it's call: core\Mage\Adminhtml and core\Mage\Customer, always inside controllers.

Anybody have any clue? There's a few more with with this behaviour, alll of them user messages.

Comment: It usually comes down to store settings. Can you make sure you've assigned a correct locale to your PT store? The way this works is : Magento will look for the `app/locale/pt_PT/` folder is you told it that the store view PT is in Portuguese.